# How to read component values from parent vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an input field component I created.  In the parent vue I added two of these components - field1 and field2. When either one of these components change I want to concatenate their values and add them to a third input field - field3. Field3 is not a vue component. I tried to add a ref to get the value of the component that did not emit the event, but it always comes back undefined (i.e. console.log(this.$refs.testRef.$data). What is the best way to get the value of field 1 and field2?  Lastly how do I change the value of field 3 from the onChange method?

input-field.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <input type="text" @input="valueChanged">
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
   name: 'myInput',
   props: 

      ['myName']
   ,
   emits: ["input"],

   methods:
   {

      valueChanged ()  {

        this.$emit("input",event.target.value)
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

app.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <my-input myName="field1" @input="onChange"/>
    <my-input ref="testRef" myName="field2" @input="onChange"/>
    <input id="field3" type=text/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import myInput from './components/input-field.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    myInput
  },
  
     methods: {
   onChange (val) {

     //DOESNT WORK ---->  console.log(this.$refs.testRef.$data)
     console.log(val)
     
     //get the value from field1 and the value from field2 two and combine them to set the value of field3
     //i.e. field3.value = field1.value + '\n' + field2.value
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I was going to make some codesandboxes demonstrating the different ways you can pass up a value from a child to a parent, specifically creating custom v-models and the like. However, one thing I noticed when copying your code is that inside your "valueChanged" method in your child, you are attempting to use "event" when you have not passed in the event param. This is why you're getting undefined. Change valueChanged method to valueChanged(event) {...}

Comment: ok that makes sense and it works now.  Thanks.  Is there a better way to get the value of my component.  Meaning, when an event is emitted can i simply get the value of another component without using a ref?  Or is this the correct way to do it.  I am asking because I would eventually need a lot of unique refs.

Comment: Is there a way to loop through the components in my parent vue?

Comment: Not sure exactly how you're using it. But built in the right way you can

Comment: use `v-model` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model)